# How to make each thread aware of a variable value in openmp

Tags: fortran, openmp

The dummy code below is from a Fortran app I am running.

My problem is that when `subroutine_a` is called, `j` has not taken the right value.

```
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, limit
    j = i+k
    call subroutine_a(j)
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

If it's running in 4 threads for example, each thread must have `j=1`, `j=2`, `j=3`, `j=4`. Right now `j` might be `1` in all 4 threads.

Comment: [I'm no expert on OpenMP, but...]  Doesn't your edit with `j=i+j` change the question quite significantly in a couple of ways?  There's the private/existing before issue, and the lack of a clear "order" on the iterations.

Comment: You're right, it probably does, but I'm trying to write something simplified to makes sense out of, since the code I am trying to parallelize is 5k+ lines, and I've never fiddled with openmp before.

Comment: I think the previous version of the question was valid, and you got a good answer, so rolling back may be best.  You can always ask a new question covering the new areas (linking back to this one).  That said, Alexander Vogt likely has a much better idea of the value of these aspects than I have.

Comment: Right, I'll remove the extra stuff and enter a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you experience is called a *race condition*. All threads write to the same, shared variable `j` so it is more or less random, which of the values will be given to the subroutine.

You have two possibilities to solve this issue:

1. Avoid it completely (if you can, i.e. if `j` is not re-used later on):

```
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, limit
    call subroutine_a(i+k)
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

2. Declare `j` private, s.t. each thread has each own version of `j`:

```
!$omp parallel do private(j)
do i = 1, limit
    j = i+k
    call subroutine_a(j)
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

Comment: Noting that this first may not be possible as the argument is now an expression rather than a variable.  [Entirely depends on stuff we don't know.]

Comment: @francescalus That is true in general (we don't know what else is done with `j`), but for the provided snippet 1. is a valid option (`j` is not used again).

Comment: Agreed - a perfectly valid option when allowed.

Comment: @francescalus I clarified the answer ;-)

Comment: @alexander-vogt Specifying it as private doesn't work, as j exists before and after the loop. This gives gives j very different results from what is expected. I filled the vars with some dummy code to get the output, I'm gonna update the question to see.

Comment: I think you have a conceptional mistake in there... In the serial version, `j` equals `limit+k` at the end of the loop (at least in the version you posted here).  You can easily set this value afterwards.

Comment: yeah but each loop will give different results as the calls won't be right. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe I should make a copy of j inside the parallel section and use that as shared?

Comment: Removed the new part, will post it as a new question. I think my answer for j lies in firstprivate for that one, but have a look when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think `i` also needs to be private...

Comment: That is not true, all loop counters are implicitly private in OMP DO.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification! Wasnt aware of that but it makes sense though. Is that true for nested loops that aren't parallelized too?

Comment: Apparently yes, there is an answer or comment about that by Hristo Iliev somewhere, but I normally declare them private to be explicit.